# C# MDI can't populate listbox on child form

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox, mdi

I am trying to populate a listbox in C# from a table in sql server. The table is set up as: 
tblTables
TableID int
SeatingCapacity int
CurrentCapacity int

The code I am trying to use is:

```
private void fillListBox()
    {
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        String commandString = "SELECT TableID, SeatingCapacity, CurrentCapacity from tblTables";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        conn.Open();            
        cmd.CommandText = commandString;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        lstTableList.Items.Clear();
        lstTableList.BeginUpdate();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            lstTableList.Items.Add(dr.GetInt32(0) + " - " + dr.GetInt32(1) + " - " + dr.GetInt32(2));
        }
        lstTableList.EndUpdate();
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();


    }
```

And the code for the parent form to transfer is:

```
private void mnuFormsTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTables aTables = new frmTables();
        aTables.MdiParent = this;
        aTables.Show();
        aTables.Focus();
    }
```

I call fillListBox() is the form load of frmTables. However when I put a break point on

```
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

It shows that right after that line the code jumps to the parent form at

```
aTables.Show();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also not sure if that is the proper way to populate the listbox either. Preferably it would be nice if the listbox could show the table ID and add "Full" beside it if the current capacity >= seating capacity.
The github repo URL for this is https://github.com/resistince/StaufferRestaurant

EDIT: If I use:

```
 String connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.StaufferRestaurantConnectionString;
```

instead of using the ConfigurationManager it works. I have System.Configuration.dll as a reference and the proper using statement so I don't know why it doesn't work right.

Comment: You probably misspelled the connectionString in the app.settings. this will explain why you get the error and also why it's hard for you to find it, since when you look at the code everything looks fine.

Comment: The hard coded string that I am using now is copied directly from the app.config

Comment: I meant you probably misspelled the connectionString key in the app.config, perhaps conectionString instead of connectionString. Sorry for not being clear about that.